# Android getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) error

Tags: java, android, serial-port, usb

I'm new at Android and I'm trying to use Android USB to send some data. I tried to use this example code

```
// Get UsbManager from Android.
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

// Find the first available driver.
UsbSerialDriver driver = UsbSerialProber.acquire(manager);

if (driver != null) {
  driver.open();
  try {
    driver.setBaudRate(115200);

    byte buffer[] = new byte[16];
    int numBytesRead = driver.read(buffer, 1000);
    Log.d(TAG, "Read " + numBytesRead + " bytes.");
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // Deal with error.
  } finally {
    driver.close();
  } 
}
```

and I'm getting this error

> The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type TCPClient

I'm not sure if I'm missing some points. Any help would be great. I'm using Eclipse Juno and JDK 1.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getSystemService(String)` is a method defined for `Context` class: `Context#getSystemService(String)`. Since Activity is a subclass of Context, using `this.getSystemService(String)` or simply `getSystemService(String)` works fine inside an Activity.

But, it seems like you are trying to use this method inside a class named `TCPClient`. And the error is pointing out that `TCPClient#getSystemService(String)` is not defined: correct.

You should either pass the Activity's Context to `TCPClient`and use it as:

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) 
                       passedContext.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
```

Or if TCPClient is an inner class to your Activity, the following should work too:

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) 
                  YourActivityName.this.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
```